# Set of all triangles with two equal edges inscribed in a circle.

Tags: geometry

Let $\Delta$ be the set of all triangles with two equal edges inscribed in a circle of radius $R$.

So, how do I show that:

1,  The equilateral triangle in $\Delta$ is the one maximizing the area.

2, The equilateral triangle in $\Delta$ is the one maximizing the circumference?

Help greatly appreciated!

Comment: by circumference you mean perimeter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can [prove](http://www.proofwiki.org/wiki/Isosceles_Triangles_have_Two_Equal_Angles) that Isosceles Triangles have Two Equal Angles

Now using [Law of Sines](http://www.proofwiki.org/wiki/Law_of_Sines),  $$\frac a{\sin A}=\frac b{\sin B}=\frac c{\sin C}=2R$$

Let $A=B=x\implies C=\pi-2x,\sin C=\sin(\pi-2x)=\sin 2x$

So, $x=A>0$ and $\pi-2x=C>0\implies x<\frac\pi2\implies 0<x<\frac\pi2$

So, $a=b=2R\sin x,c=2R\sin2x$

So, the [circumference](http://www.cliffsnotes.com/study_guide/Formulas-Perimeter-Circumference-Area.topicArticleId-18851,articleId-18807.html) will be $=a+b+c=2R(2\sin x+\sin2x)$ where $R$ is constant

and the [area](http://www.proofwiki.org/wiki/Area_of_Triangle_in_Terms_of_Circumradius) will be $\frac{abc}{4R}=\frac{(2R\sin x)^2(2R\sin2x)}{4R}=4R^2\sin^3x\cos x$ where $R$ is constant

We can apply [Second Derivative Test](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SecondDerivativeTest.html) w.r.t. $x$, to find the required extreme values as follows

Let $f(x)=2\sin x+\sin2x\implies f'(x)=2(\cos x+\cos2x)$

For the extreme values of $f(x),f'(x)=0$

$\implies \cos2x+\cos x=0\implies 2\cos^2x+\cos x-1=0$
$\implies \cos x=\frac{-1\pm\sqrt{1^2-4\cdot2\cdot(-1)}}{2\cdot2}=-1$ or $\frac12$

As $0<x<\frac\pi2,\cos x>0\implies \cos x=\frac12\implies x=\frac\pi3$

$$\text{ Now, show that  }f''(\frac\pi3)<0$$

Let $g(x)=8\sin^3x\cos x$ which can be simplified to $2\sin2x-\sin4x$ (See the comment below)

For $g'(x)=0,$ $4(\cos2x-\cos4x)=0\implies 2\cos^22x-\cos2x-1=0$

$$\implies \cos2x=1\text{ or }-\frac12$$

As $0<x<\frac\pi2\implies 0<2x<\pi \implies \cos x\ne1\implies \cos 2x=-\frac12=\cos\frac{2\pi}3$

$\implies 2x=2n\pi\pm \frac{2\pi}3\implies 2x=\frac{2\pi}3\iff x=\frac\pi3$ as $0<2x<\pi$

Now, show that $g''(\frac\pi3)<0$

Some generalization can be found [here](http://www.cut-the-knot.org/triangle/InscribedEquilateral.shtml) and [here](http://www.leadinglesson.com/problem-on-finding-the-inscribed-triangle-of-maximal-area)

Comment: $8\sin^3x\cos x$ can be simplified to $2(3\sin x-\sin3x)\cos x=3(2\sin x\cos x)-2\sin3x\cos x=3\sin2x-(\sin4x+\sin2x)=2\sin2x-\sin4x$

Answer (score 1):

Say the angle between the two equal edges of the triangle is $\theta$. Can you work out the lengths of the edges as a function of $\theta$? Once you have the lengths of the edges can you find the area and perimeter (I'm assuming that's what you meant by circumference) with respect to $\theta$, and then maximize?

Answer (score 0):

We shall prove that the inscribed equilateral triangle has maximal area  and maximal circumference  among **all** inscribed triangles; a fortiori it then has maximal area, resp. circumference, among inscribed isosceles triangles.

For both questions the optimal triangle is acute: If the angle at $C$ is $>{\pi\over2}$ reflect $C$ at the diameter parallel to $c$ and obtain a triangle that obviously has larger area as well as larger circumference. Therefore we may assume that the midpoint $M$ of the circle is in the interior of our triangle $\Delta$. Denote by $\phi_i$ $\ (1\leq i\leq 3)$ the angles under which the three sides of $\Delta$ are seen from $M$, and let $r$ be the radius of the circle. Then
$${\rm area}(\Delta)={r^2\over2}\sum_{i=1}^3\sin \phi_i\ .$$
Now $0<\phi_i<\pi$ $\ (1\leq i\leq 3)$. Since the function $\sin$ is concave in the interval $[0,\pi]$ Jensen's inequality tells us that
$${1\over3}\sum_{i=1}^3\sin \phi_i\leq \sin\left({1\over3}\sum_{i=1}^3 \phi_i\right)=\sin{2\pi\over3}={\sqrt{3}\over2}\ ;$$
and furthermore that we have strict inequality unless all $\phi_i={2\pi\over3}$. It follows that
$${\rm area}(\Delta)\leq{3\sqrt{3}\over4}\ r^2\ ,$$
and that we have equality sign only for equilateral inscribed triangles.

Similarly
$${\rm circumference}(\Delta)=2r\sum_{i=1}^3\sin{\phi_i\over2}\ ,$$
and the same argument as above proves that
$${\rm circumference}(\Delta)\leq3\sqrt{3}\ ,$$
with equality only for equilateral triangles.